# Custom styling on md icon

Tags: css, angular-material

I want to use an material design icon but for some reason the material team have decided to add a box and circle to the icon. I want to use the `account_box` icon but without the box.

I've hacked together this example: https://plnkr.co/edit/7z0XbZ?p=preview

Which uses this css:

```
.circle {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle .filler {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 22px;
}

.circle i {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px;
  color: red;
}
```

But this is a horrible solution. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you a designer by any chance? The reason I ask is that I usually create my own glyph library separate from what primary pack I'm using for my project. Often I face issues like this in projects. I create my vectors (in your case it can contain vectors just like this one without the background), and I create the lib using the tool at icomoon.io. You'd store this lib local to your project (or store in your CDN), and then load the lib via CSS `@import`, and then use via CSS using `font-family: 'myglyphs'`, and `content: '\x123'.`

Comment: I'm not a designer, and in our project we do have a supporting font pack created by our designer. But we wanted to get rid of it (extra loading etc) that's why we want to fully implement material design.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that you found exactly what you needed. But regarding load time for a custom-made glyph lib, the load would be incredibly minimal, and I doubt noticeable at all. But I can respect the wish to optimize. Best of luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked an icon: `person`, does exactly what I needed.